# Trying to understand bind_param (can't edit variables or else nothing will save)

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to make this part of the code work. 
1. I don't understand what "ssi" is. 
2. If i only want the firstname and remove the lastname in both places the code will not work anymore. why is that?

So by doing the second step i can't edit and adjust my code. I only want the firstname to be there and not the lastname but it doesn't work if i delete those lastname variables. Can't understand why? Can you help me.

Thanks for your time

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?
WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument ("ssi" in your case) is a format string that tells `bind_param` what types of arguments are being bound to it. "s" stands for "string" and "i" stands from "integer". Here you have a series made up of two strings (the first and last name) followed by an integer (the id).

If you want to remove the last name, you should remove it from the `set` clause, remove its bound variable and remove the corresponding "s" from the format string:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ? WHERE id = ?"))
# Updating lastname was removed here -------------------------^
{
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $firstname, $id);
    # s removed --------^
    # $lastname remoed ----------------^

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Yes i figured it out 20 seconds agoooo, AAAAAAH. Wasted 2 hours on this haha. Thanks

Comment: What about bind_result() by the way? If i remove the $lastname there it gets an error. Can't figure that out either. It's really stupid of me, can you please explain

Comment: @user10320039 what `bind_result`? You don't have such a call in the snippet you shared.

Comment: `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($firstname, NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();`

Comment: @user10320039 If you have another question, please use another post to ask it.